# META-INF/resources not works properly with @EnableWebMVC in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

## 1.

I'm working with Spring Boot. My Main class very simple

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

#2. Now I would like to make my static content externalised into a jar file. So, below is the jar project

```
/pom.xml
/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/hello.json // here is my resource
```

I do `maven install` and put the dependency into the main app, run the app normally. Now I can invoke `http://localhost:8080/hello.json` to get my hello.json file

#3. Then, the next step is using the Apache Tiles for my main web project, so I create a `@EnableWebMvc` class to configure the `tilesViewResolver`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    public @Bean TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        return new TilesViewResolver();
    }

    public @Bean TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer ret = new TilesConfigurer();
        ret.setDefinitions(new String[] { "classpath:tiles.xml" });
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Then I started again the application and try the `hello.json` to ensure everything still works properly. But, the 404 page appear. Delete the `WebMvcConfiguration` give back my `hello.json`.

What configuration I should do to resolve this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spring MVC, using XML configuration, you have to have a tag like the following to service static content:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"/>
```

This insinuates that Spring Boot is doing *something* to automatically guess that you have static content and properly setup the above example in META-INF/resources.  It's not really "magic", but rather that they have a default Java Configuration using `@EnableWebMvc` that has some pretty reliable default values.

When you provide your own `@EnableWebMvc`, my guess is you are over-writting their "default" one.  In order to add back a resource handler, you would do something like this:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
}
```

This is equivalent to the XML above.

Comment: Correct, I think. Just remove the `@EnableWebMvc` to switch the Boot features back on.

Aside: JSP support is pretty poor at the minute, so Tiles is probably a non-starter. Consider using Thymeleaf, or wait for JSP to catch up.

Comment: I had the same issue. From looking at the code, default locations are "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" . I put an image in src/main/resources/static/image.jpg, built and ran my project, and was able to access the image at localhost:8080/image.jpg